# Вопрос про методы r('') и f('')

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Вот пример когда изучаешь или кодишь столкнулся с методами
**r('')** и **f('')**

```
f'{"quoted string"}'
```

и

```
r('quoted string')
```

вот понятно что первая это как бы *set*
а вот вторая как бы *tuples*

Не могу понять разницу просто ?

Comment: Без контекста сложно ответить. Выглядит как 2 разных метода с разными названиями

Comment: Читайте документацию этих методов

Comment: примите ответ, если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 7):

Это не методы, а префиксы строк, пишутся без круглых скобок, т.е. `r''` и `f''`.

- `f''` -- это f-строки, они используются для форматирования
- `r''` -- это raw-строки, в них экранирование не происходит, например строка `r'a\b\c'` без `r` должна быть записана как `'a\\b\\c'`

---

> `f'{"quoted string"}'`
>
> вот понятно что первая это как бы set

Нет, тут фигурные скобки не про литерал множества, а для создания мест выполнения кода в f-строках.

Например:

```
a = 1
b = 2
print(f"c = {a + b}")
# c = 3
```

---

> `r('quoted string')`
>
> а вот вторая как бы tuples

Неа, это строка, для того, чтобы там был кортеж, в круглых скобках должен быть еще элемент или хотя бы запятая, типа: `('123',)`. А без этого, круглые скобки не должны считаться и останется только `r'quoted string'`

Comment: @Atabekdemurtaza, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 4):

Это вообще-то не методы, а специальные строки: f-строки и r-строки.

- `f-строка` (от слова format) содержит прям внутри себя код. Пример:

  ```
  >>> print(f'2+2 = {2 + 2}')
  2+2 = 4
  ```
- `r-строка` (от слова raw) все что содержит — содержит буквально:

  ```
  >>> print(r"\n")
  \n
  # vs.
  >>> print("\n") # adds newline
  ```

Comment: Так называемые f-строки введены в Python3,чтобы прежде всего сгружать переменные прям через строку.

Comment: @Константин угу...